# Hyperfinite II$_1$-factor

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

1.What is the definition of hyperfinite II$_1$-factor? Can anyone show me concrete examples?

2.If $R$ is a hyperfinite II$_1$-factor ,we can define the ultraproduct of $R^{\omega}=l^\infty(R)/I_{\omega}$,where $\omega $ is any free ultrafilter.Is $I_{\omega}$ nuclear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A II$_1$ factor is an infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebra that has trivial centre and a faithful trace. It is *hyperfinite* (or AFD, or amenable) if it has a (sot, wot, $\sigma$-wot, $\sigma$-sot, etc.) dense subalgebra that is an increasing union of finite-dimensional C$^*$-algebras.

There is a unique hyperfinite II$_1$, factor, often denoted by $R$. Common ways to construct it are, among others,

- As a group algebra,
  $$
  (\mathbb C \, \mathbb S_\infty)''\subset B(H_\lambda), 
  $$
  where $\lambda:S_\infty\to B(H_\infty)$ is the left regular representation and $S_\infty$ is the group of finite permutations of $\mathbb N$.
- As $\overline{\bigotimes_{n\in\mathbb N} M_2(\mathbb C)}^{sot}\subset B(H)$, where $H$ comes from the GNS representation of the trace.
- $\overline{{\rm UHF}(2^\infty)}^{sot}\subset B(H)$, where $H$ comes from the GNS representation of the trace.
- $L^\infty[0,1]\rtimes \mathbb R$, where $\mathbb R$ acts by translation, i.e. $s\cdot f=f(s\dotplus\cdot)$, where $\dotplus$ is addition modulo $1$.

As for $I_\omega$, it is non-separable as a C$^*$-algebra (it is an ideal in a von Neumann algebra), so asking about its nuclearity is weird. I would say that it is not nuclear (because I would expect its double dual to not be semidiscrete), but I'm not entirely sure how to argue about it.

Comment: For non-separable C*-algebras to be nuclear is not weird, e.g. AF-algebras. However $\mathcal R$ is an ideal in $I_\omega$ (embedded as $x \mapsto (x,0,0,\cdots))$ and $\mathcal R$ is not nuclear. So $I_\omega$ cannot be nuclear.

Comment: Are you sure the last example is the hyperfinite type $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor. It seems more likely to be the $\mathrm{II}_\infty$ one.

Comment: @Epsilon: I don't follow. Nuclearity does not pass to subalgebras. And AF C$^*$-algebras are separable.

Comment: @Adrián: you are probably right. I didn't think much about it, I wanted to quickly write $R$ as a crossed product.

Comment: I mean AF algebras in the sense of being locally approximated by finite dimensional algebras, which is the same as being a sequential inductive limit of those if the algebra is separable.

Comment: Furthermore, any crossed product $L^\infty(X) \rtimes G$  with a  free  ergodic  p.m.p.   action  of  an  amenable countable group $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal R$.

Comment: Yes, I somehow knew that result in some corner of my mind. Regarding nuclearity, definitely not an expert but I'm not aware of an infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebra known to be nuclear; is there any?

Comment: Yes, for example every commutative von Neumann algebra is nuclear. However, I don't know off my head why  $\mathcal R$ is not (Maybe it contains a non-exact subalgebra ?) It would be interesting to know if there are more nuclear von Neumann algebras ... .

Comment: Yes, of course. I meant "not type I". Nuclearity already fails at I$_\infty$, it would be a real surprise to me if any von Neumann algebra with nonzero II or III component is nuclear.